# internal link for using lightbox (fancyBox) in a d3 script

Tags: d3.js, hyperlink, fancybox, lightbox, internal

I'm quite new to web programming and its more or less like searching for a funcion and trying until stuff works. So you have an idea of my skill ;)

I'm trying to build a d3 visualization (after Mike Bostocks dendrogramm: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063570).
Within the tree I want to use internal links to a hidden div (with id='test') that uses a lightbox script (fancyBox: http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/).

So far, my d3 script produces following code for the link (copied from firebug):

```
<a class="fancybox" x="10" href="#test"><text class="nodeText" dy=".35em" text-anchor="start" style="fill-opacity: 1;" x="10"test</text>
```

When I'm using this code anywhere else (even in the d3-div) it works fine opening the lightbox div. But when I click on it within the d3 canvas it doesn't work.

The code for setting up the nodes and their properties (to create the code above) is as following:

```
 nodeEnter.append("svg:a")
        .attr("x", function(d) {
            return d.children || d._children ? -10 : 10;
        })      
        .attr("xlink:href", function(d){return d.url;})  // <-- reading the new "url" property
        .attr('class', 'fancybox')
    .append("text")
        .attr("dy", ".35em")
        .attr('class', 'nodeText')
        .attr("text-anchor", function(d) {
            return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start";
        })
        .text(function(d) {
            return d.name;
        })
        .style("fill-opacity", 0);
```

Furthermore, when I set an external url this works also fine. But when url is '#test' it doesn't.

I cannot find any articles for such an issue (maybe I have to spcial desires? O.o). Is there another way to setup internal links or did I missed any sign? I'm wondering why this works outside d3 but not within.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem, building my own lightbox after Jim Nielsons tutorial (https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/super-simple-lightbox-with-css-and-jquery--webdesign-3528). Watch out for the comments on recent versions of jquery.

The solution after having a working lightbox as desired is, to include the code into the d3 script somewhere (I put it to the end). Et voila!

It's not good to have blackboxes in your own code :)

Answer (score 0):

Done.

```
nodeEnter.append("image")
 .attr("xlink:href", function(d) { return d.icon; })        

 .on("click", function(d){
   var link=document.createElement("a");
   link.id="lightLink";
   link.href= d.url;
   link.rel="lightbox";
   this.appendChild(link);
   document.getElementById("lightLink").click();       
 })

 .attr("x", "-12px")
 .attr("y", "-12px")
 .attr("width", "24px")
 .attr("height", "24px");
```

Comment: Done? Wouldn't it be helpful for future visitors if you elaborated a bit on what this awesome piece of code does?